# Using boolean operations for the by function in R

Tags: r, boolean

I'm trying to search my data for indices when "has video" and "has image" are both 1. The code I wrote however, keeps giving me an error message.

Is there a different operation I should use or am I simply putting in the operations for "by" incorrectly?

> by(fz$total_raised, fz$has_video == 1 && fz$has_image == 1, summary)
>
> by(fz$total_raised, fz[has_video == 1 && has_image == 1], summary)
>
> by(fz$total_raised, fz(has_video == 1 && has_image == 1), summary)

Thank you helping me out.

Comment: I tried using the aggregate() function, and it spit out the result I wanted. However, I would still like to know how to use the by() function to do the same thing.

Comment: aggregate(fz$total_raised, by = list(fz$has_video == 1, fz$has_image == 1), FUN = "mean")

Comment: If I understand correctly what your are trying to achieve by "searching" your data, then you don't need `by`, but only subsetting. E.g.: `summary(fz$total_raised[fz$has_video == 1 & fz$has_image == 1])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you want this:

```
by(tz$total_raised, tz$has_video == 1 & tz$has_image == 1, summary)
```

Comment: It was "&" not "&&".

Are you kidding me?! I have so much to learn about R.

Thank you for showing me this!